# Saving SQL Timestamp in PHP $_SESSION

Tags: php, sql, session

Okay, so I cannot seem to save the timestamp created in my DB into my session, making it unavailable on other pages.

Everything else works as expected, the timestamp variable is set and available to the current page, but for whatever reason is not available on other pages.

Here is the relevant script portion, hopefully someone can pick out where i have gone wrong.

```
 if (isset($_GET['id']) && !$_POST) {
// prepare SQL query
 $sql = 'SELECT 
         id, menu, item, description, price, DATE_FORMAT(updated, "%b %d %Y " "@" " %h:%i %p") 
         FROM 
        `menus` WHERE id = ?';
if ($stmt->prepare($sql)) {
// bind the query parameter
$stmt->bind_param('i', $_GET['id']);
// bind the results to variables
$stmt->bind_result($id, $menu, $item, $description, $price, $updated);
// execute the query, and fetch the result
$OK = $stmt->execute();
$stmt->fetch();
 }
}

// if form has been submitted, update record
if (isset($_POST ['update'])) {

// prepare update query 
$sql = 'UPDATE menus 
        SET menu = ?, item = ?, description = ?, price = ?, updated = NOW()
        WHERE id = ?';

if ($stmt->prepare($sql)) {
$stmt->bind_param('ssssi', $_POST['menuChoice'], 
                           $_POST['item'], 
                           $_POST['description'], 
                           $_POST['price'], $_POST['id']);
$done = $stmt->execute();
}
```

SESSION PORTION

```
$update_message = '<h1 class="green">Last Update: ' 
. '<span class="font_size_001">' 
. $updated 
. '</span>' 
. '</h1>' 
. '<p>The following item was updated successfully:';
$confirm_Array = array($update_message, $_POST['menuChoice'], $_POST['item'], $_POST['price'], $_POST['description'], $_POST['updated']);
$_SESSION['confirm'] = $confirm_Array;
```

In the above you will notice i have tried to use just the bound variable "`$update`" as well as saving the "`$_POST['update']`" in the session, neither option works.

Page 2 (where i am attempting to display this information)

```
foreach ($_SESSION['confirm'] as $updated)
{
echo $updated . '<br />';
}
```

Everything works as expected except to the timestamp.

Comment: Post your solution as an answer, so that others may find it easier instead of having it jumbled in with your question.

Comment: check if that column has any data. Could be its null.

Comment: no, column has data. The variable works fine on the current page, it just wont load into a session. I can get around this by making the session the last thing in the script; however this breaks everything else.